# Why is SP1 for Vista not offered by Windows Update?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, service-pack

I am dealing with an OEM computer by FSC with Vista Home Basic 32-bit.

I run `winver` to check the version and it says it's 6.0 build 6000. If SP2 was to be installed it would say build 6002. And yes, I know that the SP2 for Vista is incremental - meaning it requires SP1 to be installed first. But then again, where the h... is it then?

The `systeminfo` command reveals that the original installation date is 2007-09-30. So there is no bloody way that this is a case where other Windows updates that were required for SP1 were not present on the system. Some Microsoft KB articles suggest that one has to "wait out" for these updates to be installed first before SP is offered.

This computer has been used for over 5 years! And Windows Update is set to find and install updates automatically. How much longer does this user have to wait?

Why was SP1 never pushed through Windows Update on this system?

Comment: Did you checked there is no pending update for that system ever? May be this [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948343) can resolve your problem.

Comment: Have you tried [the standalone installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30)? Was Windows installed from original install media, or was it modified (with software like vLite)? Also related: http://superuser.com/q/18720/108226 (accepted answer links to same KB article as @avirk above).